# using a variable in MYSQL limits in subquery

Tags: mysql, loops, limit

I'm trying to recreate some code I did in SQL server on mySQL. I want to insert a row for every row in a table. I am using a loop to do this, in SQL server I used SELECT TOP @foo

here is my mySQl

```
    begin
    set @maxloop = (select max(id) from `LeagueInfo`);
    set @loopno = 1;

    while @loopno <= @maxloop DO

SET @mtop = (select `teams` * `homegames` from `LeagueInfo` where id = @loopno);
SET @div = (select `LeagueShortName` from `LeagueInfo` where id = @loopno);
SET @teams = (select teams from `LeagueInfo` where id = @loopno);
SET @homegames = (select homegames from `LeagueInfo` where id = @loopno);


SET @fthgsum = (select sum(`FTHG`)/@teams/@homegames from `footy` where `id` in(select`id`, `div` from `footy`
        where `div` = @DIV
        order by `matchdate` desc LIMIT @mtop));
SET @ftagsum = (select sum(`FTAG`)/@teams/@homegames from `footy` where `id` in(select`id`, `div` from `footy`
        where `div` = @DIV
        order by `matchdate` desc LIMIT @mtop));
insert into `looptable` (`di`, `homeav`, `awayav`) values (@div, @fthgsum,@fthgsum);
        set @loopno = @loopno +1;
   END while;
    END;
```

I get an error on limit @mtop. I've read that I can get round this with a prepared statement but I'm not sure how to do it in a subquery. Is there a was to do this or is there another was I can select the top x amount of rows based on a value in another table for each row in that table.

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0):

In your line of code,

`SET @mtop = (select 'teams' * 'homegames' from 'LeagueInfo' where id = @loopno)`

`mtop` is not a number, which is false since limit needs to be a number.

maybe you want to use "count(*)"?

Comment: teams and homegames are int so that should make @mtop a number I think

Comment: But what does the entire "select" statement return, is it rows or a number?

Comment: a number because it should only select one row due to the where clause.

Comment: Even if it is just one row, the data type returned by the select is always a "row", which is plain inappropriate to be used as a limit. Use "Count(*)"

Comment: I need the limit number to be homegames * teams, how can I 'count' that. I tried it as select sum(homegames * teams) but it still didnt like it

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Using Select you can only retrieve rows. Are you trying to multiply total teams and total homegames?

Comment: the table league info has the number of homegames and the number of teams for each league. I want to find homegames * games = ? and use ? as my limit. how do I lookup values in a table without select?